# Unity 2019.3.7f1 ios not building

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, dll, build

```
System.Windows.Forms.dll assembly is referenced by user code, but is not supported on iOS platform. Various failures might follow.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:187)
```

I don't have such usage in my project.

Comment: Is that added to your project as a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so apparently the problem was in project being on a remote SSD drive. In my case I use MacOS and drive is set up with some Windows file system, that could be the problem.

Deleting Temp, restarting Unity and PC didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you search in all your files for "Forms"? It is quite possible that there's a reference hiding somewhere, especially if you used some code from the Asset Store or some posts online.